# Get Websocket messages with Selenium or any way to capture web socket message with python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

Is it possible to get websocket messages with Selenium Webdriver with python? Or any other to way capture or crawl websocket message on specific site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'pyppeteer' library for this

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
 
 
async def main():
    browser = await launch(
        headless=False,
        args=['--no-sandbox'],
        autoClose=False
    )
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://example.com')
    cdp = await page.target.createCDPSession()
    await cdp.send('Network.enable')
    await cdp.send('Page.enable')
    def printResponse(response):
        print(response)
 
    cdp.on('Network.webSocketFrameReceived', printResponse) # Calls printResponse when a websocket is received
    cdp.on('Network.webSocketFrameSent', printResponse) # Calls printResponse when a websocket is sent
    await asyncio.sleep(2000)
 
 
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Tell me, how do I call page.click() from inside printResponse() function? I need click based on message received from socket.